# Does (Exclusive) XML Canonicalization ignore whitespaces outside tags (indentation)?

Tags: xml, canonicalization

When XML must be canonicalized according to http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/,
should the following pieces of XML become equals?
(note, the `.` character stands for a `' '` space)

```
<a>
.<b>
..<c>data</c>
.</b>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
...<b>
......<c>data</c>
...</b>
</a>
```

In other words: does Exclusive Canonicalization ignore whitespaces? (or ignore indent-size)

Or, should indentations remain the same? 
And how about the first one?
Will the canoncialized version of `<b>` (from the seconds example) become

```
...<b>
......<c>data</c>
...</b>
```

or

```
<b>
......<c>data</c>
...</b>
```

or

```
<b>
...<c>data</c>
</b>
```

Comment: I didn't find anything about indents or white-spaces in http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n either

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-c14n/#N100A1 gives a nice explanation. But I'm still not sure if indentation can be seen as  content in this sentence:'All whitespace in character content is retained (excluding characters removed during line feed normalization).'

Comment: http://books.google.nl/books?id=64FC8sZ74jQC&lpg=PA102&ots=8C3-rmk1mx&dq=%22All%20whitespace%20in%20character%20content%20is%20retained%22&hl=nl&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=%22All%20whitespace%20in%20character%20content%20is%20retained%22&f=false gives an example which indicates that white space between tags is retained.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.

See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#Example-WhitespaceInContent).

In short:

`<Foo></Foo>`

and

`<Foo>
</Foo>`

Are different.

Exclusive C14n mostly just changes namespace handling to allow for removal and re-wrapping.